# Is it possible to ask reference letter from customer/client for remaining projects after resignation?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, ethics

I am working at software development and consulting industry as consultant and developer.

However, I will resign tomorrow from my current company and still do the remaining projects as part time.

So I will ask customer reference letter after my resignation and as individual.

As in my title, I wonder, can I ask reference letter from my customer/client that I work on later for my name?

Comment: Yes you can request them politely and they will do needful.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:Yes you can.

Real Question: when you should?

Suggestion: If you think you are worthy of recommendation letter then there must have been times when client/employer would have praised you verbally or on chat. You can grab that opportunity to ask for one.

If you some how missed that moment then you should only request for the letter when the relation ship is at a high.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is both Yes and No,

let me explain... You could ask your client to give you reference letter if and only if you are working solely or in your own company with that client, means you are not tied to any organization who hired you for doing developer job. If your are hired by other organization for doing job, you can't and shouldn't ask for any reference letter.

Comment: I think asking reference letter from customers is common?

Comment: Yes, but there are few consulting services which don't like it been done, as they might see it as conflict of interest between you and them (your employer)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask them, but I wouldn't. My reasoning is that I worked for them under a company, so realistically I should be getting a reference from my employer, not their customers.

Once I was freelancing for them, then that is another story and would not conflict with my ethics.

Comment: Kilisi, I am still working under same company although with different contract terms now, and I would like to ask the reference letter directly from customer later on for my name (not my company).